# Unable to register with Notification Hub in Xamarin Android project

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, azure-notificationhub, unauthorized

I have been trying to register with NH from my Xamarin Android project. I managed to configure FireBase, but when I try to register with Notification Hub on the client side I am getting Unauthorized exceptions. I am sure that I have used correct connection credentials, as I have used the same in UWP project and it works there.

Here is my code:

```
Hub = new NotificationHub(Constants.NotificationHubName, "Endpoint=sb://namespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=mykey=",
                                        context);
            try
            {
                Hub.UnregisterAll(registrationId);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(MyBroadcastReceiver.TAG, ex.Message);
            }

            var tags = new List<string>() { "droid" }; // create tags if you want
           // var tags = new List<string>() { };

            try
            {
                var hubRegistration = Hub.Register(registrationId, tags.ToArray());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(MyBroadcastReceiver.TAG, ex.Message);
            }
```

I am getting unauthorized exceptions from both methods UnregisterAll and Register. Please any advice, how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It indicates that your Notification hub credentials are wrong or invalid. Could you ensure that you are referring right Notification Hub and corresponding connection string.

On side note, you don’t need to call unregister api. Register API acts as CreateOrUpdate. It will take care of creating registration if it doesn’t exist.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I do use correct credentials. As I stated, I use the same ones as for UWP project, where the registration works.

Comment: One more note, registration work thru Push object obtained thru MobileServiceClient, but its method RegisterAsync does not allow to register tags. It works only for templates.

Comment: Check out the code in http://aka.ms/zumobook - chapter 5 - which includes code for registering with tags.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that working throuhg the MobileServiceClient works, you can register through App Service Push.  Check out http://aka.ms/zumobook - chapter 5.  This includes code for each platform on how to register with tags.